# custom module stop working after Magento 2.4.3 upgrade

Tags: magento2, php, module, amasty

I have a module that extend the functionality of other module, in fact it display the product name and product price as a variable, after I upgrade the Magento to 2.4.3 this module stop working and I observe that in frontend my js file is not loaded this is my requirejs-config.js file:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Amasty_Customform/js/form-session': {
                'Amasty_CustomFormOptionalVariables/js/form-session-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Amasty_Customform module is installed with the composer so the path is in the vendor folder and Amasty_CustomFormOptionalVariables is in the app/code folder, maybe this is problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Amasty_Customform module is installed with the composer so the path is in the vendor folder and Amasty_CustomFormOptionalVariables is in the app/code folder, maybe this is problem?

**NO it can not cause issue, make sure your cache disabled on cloudfare/server and you had unmerged css and working on developer mode**

Please run below command once

1. rm -rf var/cache/* generated/code/* var/view_preprocessed/* var/page_cache/* var/report/* pub/static/frontend/* pub/static/adminhtml/* pub/static/_cache/merged/*
2. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
3. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
4. php bin/magento setup:di:compile
5. php bin/magento indexer:reindex
6. php bin/magento cache:clean
7. php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: Hi, I try all this is still the same ....

Comment: @Robert how did you sort out the issue?